# Area under an unknown function $f(x)$ from $-1$ to $1$, given an identity in $f(x)$ and $x$

Tags: calculus, integration

(Source: MAT $2014)$

Given the following: $$6+f(x) = 2f(-x) + 3x^2\int_{-1}^{1}{}f(t)dt$$

Find the value of $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx$.

So here I tried putting in some values of $x$, in order to find something about the function, like symmetry. So putting in $x=0$ gives $f(0) = 6$. Furthermore, differentiating the equation, we get
$$f'(x) = 2f'(-x)+6x (f(1)-f(-1))$$
In this equation, putting $x=0$, it follows that $f'(0) = 2f'(0) \implies f'(0) = 0$. So the graph is symmetrical about the y-axis(I could be wrong about this, not sure). Thus, $f(x) = f(-x)$. The simplified equation is :
$$6-f(x) = 3x^2 \int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt$$
Is my conclusion about the graph of $f(x)$ being symmetrical to the y-axis correct? And how do I proceed from here?

Comment: I do not think that the differentiation was done correctly , but even if , $f'(0)=0$ does not imply that the graph is symmetrical to the $y$-axis.

Comment: Also , since the bounds are constant , "f(t)dt" can simply be replaced by "f(x)dx" , if this helps.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 f(t)\ dt$ is a constant.  When you differentiate it gets carried along as a constant.  And you forgot to apply the chain rule to $\frac d{dx} 2f(-x) = -2f'(-x)$

Comment: @user317176 would my differentiation be correct if I replaced f(t)dt by f(x)dx(ignoring the fact that I forgot to apply chain rule)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(0)=0$ is correct but your argument is wrong. I will let you correct the differentiation argument.

Just integrate your last equation from $-1$ to $1$. You get $12-\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt =2\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt$ so $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt=4$